# LiveData not updating after changed using Handler PostDelayed?

Tags: android, handler, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Here's my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(repository: MainActivityRepo) : ViewModel() {

val isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    isLoading.value = false
    android.os.Handler().postDelayed({
        isLoading.value = true
        Timber.d("isCalled")
    }, 5000L)
     }
}
```

I debugged and checked and the log is working perfectly.

The first value of boolean is set correctly, while the second is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On background thread, you can use post value instead of set value which will solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Vikas you should use the [postValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postvalue) method.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    isLoading.postValue(true)
    Timber.d("isCalled")
}, 5000L)
```

Comment: @ManojPerumarath you should mark one of the answers as the solution. So that your question closes.